# Azure DB Connection Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

I'm deploying an ASP.Net web site to Azure. It uses an Azure SQL database. I'm trying to set this up using a password-less connection string. I've been following the steps in a tutorial on MS Docs titled "[Tutorial: Secure Azure SQL Database connection from App Service using a managed identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi)". It works on my machine connecting to the database. I've checked and double checked the steps. The only thing that is different is the site I'm using.

The problem I'm getting is that when I deploy it to the server and it connects to the database I'm getting a cryptic error. Does anyone know what this error message means?

> [COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned
> from a call to a COM component.]
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.net45.d__20.MoveNext()
> +692    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.d__6.MoveNext()
> +535    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.d__4.MoveNext()
> +230    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.d__11.MoveNext()
> +685    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.d__8.MoveNext()
> +453    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.d__14.MoveNext()
> +974    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.d__2.MoveNext()
> +372    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) +102
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task) +64
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\ActiveDirectoryNativeAuthenticationProvider.cs:53
>
> [AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +4247326
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +12576612    System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() +34
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.<>c__DisplayClass137_1.b__1()
> in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:2723
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke() +58
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +48
>
> [AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
> includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +4247326
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,
> CancellationToken cancellationToken) +12586685
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() +16
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetFedAuthToken(SqlFedAuthInfo
> fedAuthInfo) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:2723
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OnFedAuthInfo(SqlFedAuthInfo
> fedAuthInfo) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:2581
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:2548
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\TdsParser.cs:2088
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
> enlistOK) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:1357
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
> withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir)
> in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:2239
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
> SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:1757
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
> timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:1628
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
> ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback,
> ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool
> pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo
> originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling,
> SqlAuthenticationProviderManager sqlAuthProviderManager) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlInternalConnectionTds.cs:465
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnectionFactory.cs:143
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
> pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
> DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:167
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:918
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:2024
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
> allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:1427
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionPool.cs:1310 Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
> connection) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionFactory.cs:357
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionInternal.cs:773 Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\ProviderBase\DbConnectionClosed.cs:72
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) in H:\tsaagent1\_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:1860 Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry) in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:1853
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() in
> H:\tsaagent1_work\5\s\src\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient\netfx\src\Microsoft\Data\SqlClient\SqlConnection.cs:1421

Here is the relevant snippet from the web.config file. I've changed the name of the server and database in the connection string so they remain secret.

```
<configSections>
  <section name="exceptionFilters" type="MGBrownWeb.Configuration.ErrorFilterSection" allowDefinition="Everywhere" allowExeDefinition="MachineToApplication" restartOnExternalChanges="true" />
  <section name="SqlAuthenticationProviders" type="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlAuthenticationProviderConfigurationSection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
</configSections>
<SqlAuthenticationProviders>
  <providers>
    <add name="Active Directory Interactive" type="Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication.SqlAppAuthenticationProvider, Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication" />
  </providers>
</SqlAuthenticationProviders>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyDB" connectionString="server=tcp:my-server-tst-sqls.database.windows.net;database=database-tst-sqldb-1;UID=AnyString;Authentication=Active Directory Interactive" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What's the connectionstring?

Comment: @Charlieface I've added it to the end of the question. I've changed the server and database names a bit for security.

Comment: Are you using Azure AD? And doesn't this require an MFA dialog box to pop up? You need to follow something like [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi) to make it work

Comment: That's the exact tutorial I followed. I'm using a SystemAssigned identity on the web app.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had referenced Microsoft.Data.SqlClient from one of my projects instead of System.Data.SqlClient. Changing back to System.Data.SqlClient resolved the error.

Comment: Isn't Microsoft.Data.SqlClient necessary for Azure AD authentication though?

Comment: They keep changing these things. I can't keep track of it, it was probably a bug in a now obsolete version. I asked this question 2 & 1/2 years ago and then moved on.